# Which files do malware reside in after visiting a malicious site

Tags: malware

I've been really on edge about accidently visiting a malicious site in the the past month, so please excuse how badly explained this question may be.
About twenty minutes ago I was visiting a site to help me with something when I was redirected to one of those scam sites which say "You've won a free phone!" Along with two other sites that I did not take the time to check. Imdetiently I left the sites, and went to remove them from my browsing history which seemed to lag a bit while doing so, so I ended up clearing my cache.

My phone began to run alower than usual which from what I've read is a sign of malware installed (?) Currently I haven't seen any new applications installed though I double checked folders and saw one which seemed kinda suspicious which was title ".1VRecord" which had a ton of strange file combination inside. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to double check for malware or what files they would tend to hide in? Thanks!

Comment: Hello. First, calm down. Second, reboot the device and see if the device still lags during usage. Third, clearing cache won't remove history items of your browser. Your history might be long (which browser is it?) so you can clear data of your browser app from Settings app (but do note that it would remove everything from your browser). Fourth, tell us which Android device, Android version, and browser app and its version are you using? Fifth, a myriad of apps abuse internal storage area to store files with bizarre names...

Comment: ...but that doesn't mean they all are a sign of a malware. Sixth, use [this app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.majeur.applicationsinfo/) and use its top bar settings to list apps in the order of installation time. Tell us which app and relevant date time do you see as first entry.

Comment: another possible reason google play services sometimes roll-out broken updates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Worried about possible malware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233231/worried-about-possible-malware)